# Menu icon vertical align

Tags: css, icons, alignment

The menu icon, class="fa fa-bar" in the nav bar of this page: 
https://www.theairlinepilots.com/tapforum/forum-header.php
is not vertically aligned when seen on a cell phone chrome browser, but it is vertically aligned when seen on a desktop chrome browser. Tried many combinations of enclosing it in divs and using -ve margin values to compensate for float effect, but no success. How can I properly vertically align it for all browsers. Thanks.
HTML

```
<div class="tap-navbar" id="my-tap-navbar">
  <a href="https://www.theairlinepilots.com/index.php" class="active">About</a>
  <a href="https://www.theairlinepilots.com/index.php">Forums</a>
  <a href="https://www.theairlinepilots.com/index.php">Flight Planning</a>
  <a href="https://www.theairlinepilots.com/index.php">Apps</a>
  <a href="https://www.theairlinepilots.com/membership-subscription.php">Membership</a>
  <a href="https://www.theairlinepilots.com/admincontact.php">Contact</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
<i class="fa fa-bars" style="color:#ffffff;vertical-align:middle;">
</a></i>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.tap-navbar {
font-family: Courier, Verdana, sans-serif, arial;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #006699;
border-radius:0px 0px 5px 5px;
margin-bottom:5px;
    background: #005580;
    background: linear-gradient(#005580,#0077b3);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#005580, #0077b3); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#005580, #0077b3);  
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#005580, #0077b3);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#005580, #0077b3);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(1, #005580),color-stop(0, #0077b3));    
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a css expert but you can apply following solution:

```
<i class="fa fa-bars" style="color:#ffffff; vertical-align:middle; height: 16px;">
```

That means add height property. Additionally a recommendation, Please use `<em>` instead of `<i>` tag. Read more https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-b-and-i-tags

Answer (score 0):

ok figured out that there was nothing wrong with the code. The problem was a conflict from phpbb forum that had the same class name 'icon'. Renaming .icon in my code solved the issue.